# How to use swift extension in objective c framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, extension-methods, xcode8.2

I've installed [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) in a Swift project through CocoaPods which is in Objective-C. And I've a UIColor extension in the Swift project.

```
public extension UIColor {
    public func appColor()->UIColor {    
        return UIColor(red: 0.525, green: 0.49, blue: 0.929, alpha: 1.0) 
    }
}
```

Now I want to call the UIColor extension method from a Objective-C .m file.

I have the following imports and still unable to access it.

[image: myApp-Swift.h file not found]

myApp is the Target name and I've tried changing "Defines Module" and "Product Module Name" in Build settings. Still I get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried different approach? `#import <myApp-Swift.h>`

Comment: Yes. I tried. Got the same error.

Comment: How are you installing `MWPhotoBrowser`? `Cocoapods`, `Carthage`, adding to the project by yourself?

Comment: As I've mentioned in my question I installed `MWPhotoBrowser` through CocoaPods.

Comment: Sry, I missed that fact. Than `MWPhotoBrowser` won't get your app classes, because Pod is separate project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Than MWPhotoBrowser won't get your app classes, because Pod is separate project. – NSDmitry